# Uncaught SyntaxError and Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have tried for hours to get this program to work but i now get these errors and dont know what i've done wrong any help is appreciated.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>  Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   start is not defined 
>  Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not
>   defined

Il put the errors in the code so you know where they are coming from.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uppgift 6</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $NS {}; <---Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        $NS.Vara = function () {
            this.namn = Mjölk;
            this.pris = 17;
            this.beskrivning= Arla 3%;
            this.antal= 40;
            this.calcSubTotal = function () {
                document.getElementById("resultat").value = this.pris * this.antal;
            };
        };
        var global;
        function start() { <---Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
            global = new $NS.Vara(); <--- Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Value" onClick="global.calcSubTotal()"/>
        <input type="text" id="resultat"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, what do you *expect* `var $NS {};` to do? How is that *not* a syntax error?

Comment: Well its an object i use as a namespace?

Comment: But how is that valid syntax?!

Comment: im new to javascript and this is how my teacher did it, dont really know what i did wrong..

Comment: Perhaps there is no equal sign, that's why it doesn't work...

Comment: wow i have no clue how i did not se that thanks.........

Comment: you also need quotes around your strings. `this.namn = Mjölk;` is invalid.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the person asking does not show the minimal amount of info to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error starts from the missing = after `var $NS`, the constant string assigned to `namn` and `beskrivning` are not enclosed by `'` or `"`.

Try:

```
var $NS = {}; <---Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
$NS.Vara = function () {
    this.namn = "Mjölk";
    this.pris = 17;
    this.beskrivning= "Arla 3%";
    this.antal= 40;
    this.calcSubTotal = function () {
        document.getElementById("resultat").value = this.pris * this.antal;
    };
};
var global;
function start() { <---Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    global = new $NS.Vara(); <--- Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
}
```